# Trouble with _unicode() method in django

Tags: django

I'm adding a **unicode**() method to my model, however when displaying all objects in the interactive it's not working.

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def _unicode_(self):
        return self.question
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    def _unicode_(self):
        return self.choice
# Create your models here.

(InteractiveConsole

>>> from polls.models import Poll, Choice
>>> Poll.objects.all()
[<Poll: Poll object>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The django docs show you how to specify a unicode method in your model:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#other-model-instance-methods

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

**Note:** These are DOUBLE underscores, where in your example you are only using single underscores.

Its a standard python special class method, [as listed here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__unicode__)

Comment: I changed my code and it's still not working. Btw according to the guide here:[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) my previous code was right.

Comment: @fpena06: No where on that link you provided does it say `_unicode`. Also, I think you are missing that it is DOUBLE underscore. The link you provided also shows double underscore `__unicode__`

Answer (score 3):

They need to be named `__unicode__` (two underscores on either side).  This is an awkward detail of Python reserved methods that is not immediately obvious by looking at them.