# Django __unicode__ still not work for me

Tags: python, django, unicode

I use django1.6 and python2.7, I have the following in my models.py.

```
class Recommend(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    master_id = models.IntegerField()
    movie_id = models.IntegerField()
    enable = models.TextField() # This field type is a guess.
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'recommend'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.id, self.master_id)
```

However, the result is still

```
>>> from movies.models import Recommend
>>> Recommend.objects.all()
[<Recommend: Recommend object>]
>>>
```

I've checked [Django tutorial unicode not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121815/django-tutorial-unicode-not-working) , [`__unicode__()` addition not working in basic poll application in Django tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357251/unicode-addition-not-working-in-basic-poll-application-in-django-tutoria), [Trouble with _unicode() method in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540054/trouble-with-unicode-method-in-django), [Python 2.7__unicode__(self) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412358/python-2-7-unicode-self-not-working). None did work for me.

Comment: Is your indentation correct in the actual code? The way you have pasted it in the question it won't work.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The actual code I wrote is correct, the format on this page has no indentation.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the indentation exactly as it is in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Recommend(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  master_id = models.IntegerField()
  movie_id = models.IntegerField()
  enable = models.TextField() # This field type is a guess.

  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'recommend'

  def __str__(self):
   return u'%s %s' % (self.id, self.master_id)
```

May be it should help

Comment: Thanks, but it still not work. I use python2.7 not python3, so maybe "from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible" doesn't work.

Comment: i also used python 2.7. Let me try it.